# How to align divs as this with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Have a layout with 3 columns, when on mobile devices, a want column 3 to be below column 2, and not below the height of column 1. Column 2 have a variable height, and can be less than the height of the photo.

My layout is like this.

```css
  .container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
}

.middle {
  flex: 1;
}

.right {
  flex: 0 0 225px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .right {
    flex: 1 100%;
    padding-left: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">a</div>
  <div class="middle">b</div>
  <div class="right">c</div>
</div>
```

The padding-left, positions the .right below the .middle, but below the bottom of the .left container. And i want to obtain the second secnario in the screenshot, so that the right column is places right below the middle column on small devices

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap the `middle` and `right`, make the `wrapper` a flex container, and then, at narrower screen, change its `flex-direction` to `column`

Also, at narrower screens, we need to set the `container` to `align-items: flex-start`, so the `left`/`wrapper` height is based on their content.

Stack snippet

```css
.container, .wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
}

.middle, .right {
  flex: 1;
}

.wrapper {
  flex: 0 0 225px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .wrapper { 
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.left, .middle, .right {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">a</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="middle">b, made this higher<br>to show how it wraps</div>
    <div class="right">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```